# Expectation of a function of a distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, expected-value

The question I'm looking at involves evaluating:

$$ E[\frac{(n-1)}{(n-1+X_n)}] $$ for n >= 2

Xn is a random variable with a negative binomial distribution, equivalent to Binomial(p, -n).

How would I go about evaluating this expectation? I've never dealt with taking the expectation of a function which used the parameter of the number of trials and don't know where to start.

I know that the solution is 1-p, but I do not know how to get there.

Comment: Just do it the standard way; compute$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{n-1+k}p_k$, where $p_k$ is the probability of $X_n=k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n-1)}{n-1+k} \binom{n+k-1}{k}p^k(1-p)^n & = & \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \binom{n+k-2}{k}p^k(1-p)^n \\
& = & (1-p)\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \binom{n+k-2}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-1} \\
& = & 1-p
\end{eqnarray}

Try to fill the missing steps by your own!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. As for your substitution for p_k -  would the exponent of (1-p) be n-k, instead of n? From my notes it seems that this would be the PMF.

Comment: @LawrenceWang Isn't the PMF exactly defined as $P(X_n=k), k=1,2,\ldots$? The expectation, by the way, is the weighted average of the PMF.

Comment: My confusion stems from the last step, where the summation is equal to one. I assume that this is because the summation expression is the PMF and the summation of all P{X = k} from k = 1 to infinity must equal one. However, the PMF of a negative binomial would have (1-p)^(n-k), would it not? Looking here: [link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/79)

Edit: Ah - were you denoting n as the number of failures, and not the number of trials? If so, that makes sense.

Comment: @LawrenceWang Thanks for the reply. I realized that there are alternative formulations of negative binomial distribution, see this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution. My version counts k successes before n failures, while yours counts n trials required given k successes. Using your definition, I failed to calculate the desired result. Is your problem using the same formulation as in your link?

Comment: I actually believe that your interpretation is correct and I interpreted it wrong, apologies.

I think I understand everything now except for the very first step. In the combination, why do we use (n+k-1) instead of (n+k)? I understand that this allows us to simplify greatly, but if n+k is the total number of trials, is that not what we would take in the top of the combination?

Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: @LawrenceWang if we adopt the interpretation that k counts the number of successes before n failures, note that the last trial must be a failure (for we are counting until there are n failures!), this leaves a total number of n+k-1 preceding trials from which we need to choose k successful trials. This explains the binomial coefficient. Then the probability of succeeding k times and failing n times is just $p^k(1-p)^n.$ Again I’m all glad to be helpful :)